# React Native - how set View size screen size independently?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'd like make View will be looked the same at different sizes (for Android 4+) and dpi (240+), as well IPhone 4+ and IPad. When I define size, ex. 270x65, it looks double size in screen with 640 dpi than same size in screen 320 dpi (2560x1600 real screen size).

Is this a good solution?

```
  containerButton: {
    width: calcDimension(270),
    height: calcDimension(65)
  }

const calcDimension = size =>
  size / (screenScale() > 2 ? (screenScale() / 2) : 1);

const screenScale = () =>
  (Dimensions.get('window').scale);
```

Or there could be better solution? Thank you.

Comment: P.S. I don't look how to calculate screen size. The main question is why View with same size  take more screen size (twice more) in 640 dpi screen in compare with same view size in screen 320 dpi?

Comment: same view size for 'button' Start and same font size, same screen size, different dpi
https://gyazo.com/6e575eebde3bb5f42226691f293dffec
https://gyazo.com/972c9f33a54a039421c0f35f6191006f

Comment: same size of view and fonts, but smaller screen and lower dpi
https://gyazo.com/be947791d6fb6505ef9e59d1c0adaf10

Comment: Let me know if following blog [Responsive Design in React Native](https://medium.com/@elieslama/responsive-design-in-react-native-876ea9cd72a8#.p7k1wgxr3) helped you.

Answer (score 6):

You can use **Dimensions** in react native to get device height and width calculated automatically.

First import Dimensions

```
import { Dimensions, Platform, StyleSheet } from 'react-native
```

Get device height and width

```
var deviceHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height;
var deviceWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;
```

Now you can use this global variable in your styles. for example:

```
const styles = StylSheet.create({
     mainContainer: {
          height: deviceHeight/2;
          width: deviceWidth/2;
     }
});
```

You can also dynamically calculate statusbar height and width standard way:

```
var STATUS_BAR_HEIGHT = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 20 : 25;
var HEADER_HEIGHT = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 44 + STATUS_BAR_HEIGHT : 44 + STATUS_BAR_HEIGHT;
```

Comment: please look to my comments after question

Answer (score 2):

I have just gone through your query and i think it would be great if you try using "dimensions" . Dimensions is another important parameter which is provided by react native it self. What you need to do is just import the dimension in your component.

```
var {height, width} = Dimensions.get('window');
```

The above command will set height and width of the device according no matter it is iphone or android.

Just go throung the link: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/dimensions.html

Cheers :)

Comment: please look to my comments after question

Answer (score 0):

you can use vw or vh to set the dimensions.

for example: height:"90vh", width:"50vw" will set height of the respective element 90% to the window size and width 50%.

Hope this helped.